# Why operator with lower precedence in JavaScript is being executed first?

Tags: javascript, function, operator-precedence

I am running a line of code that has a function call and console.log in it. According to the precedence table, The function invocation `()` operator's value is 19 while the grouping operator has the highest precedence (20). So, is not it supposed to do whatever inside the grouping first?

```
function fn() {
  console.log("foo");
}

fn() + (console.log("bar"))
```

This prints `foo` on the first line and then `bar`.

While according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) I am supposed to see:

`bar`

`foo`

What am I missing here?

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) is something different from [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity). If you read your own link a little further, it tells you that as well.

Comment: I know what associativity is. I thought associativity comes to play when the operator precedence is equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JS engine evaluates '+' operator from left to right.

Building the syntax tree the fn() is the left side node and the other statement is the right node. The interpreter evaluates the left node and puts it into the stack, then the right node and puts the result on the stack then performs the + operation to the two topmost elements on the stack.

Comment: Could you kindly tell me why would it evaluate the "+" operator first? Clearly "Function Invocation" and "Grouping" operators have higher precedence.

Comment: The JavaScript interpreter parses the JavaScript code, creates a syntax tree and then traverses and executes (evaluates the expressions) on the tree leafs. The line: fn() + (console.log("bar")) creates a binary tree with two nodes. and each of the operations (function invocation and grouping) end up on different node (leaf) and their precedence has meaning only in the tree node where they are - each node of the syntax tree is evaluated (executed) separately and then over the results is applied the + operation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanation.